# PHP - Can't catch exception thrown by Google API lib

Tags: php, exception, google-api-php-client

I want to catch an exception that is thrown by the [Google API PHP library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), but for some reason it generates a '*Fatal error: uncaught exception*' before reaching my catch block.

In my app I have something like this:

```
try {
    $google_client->authenticate($auth_code);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do something
}
```

This is [Google_Client's authenticate()](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L132):

```
public function authenticate($code)
{
    $this->authenticated = true;
    return $this->getAuth()->authenticate($code);
}
```

The `authenticate($code)` above is [Google_Auth_OAuth2::authenticate()](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php#L124), which at some point throws the exception:

```
throw new Google_Auth_Exception(
    sprintf(
        "Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: '%s'",
        $decodedResponse
    ),
    $response->getResponseHttpCode()
);
```

If I put a try/catch block in the Google_Client's authenticate, it catches the exception, but without it the program just dies instead of reaching the main try/catch block from my app.

As far as I know this shouldn't be happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem was that the try/catch block was in a namespaced file and PHP requires you to use "\Exception". More info: [PHP 5.3 namespace/exception gotcha](https://web.archive.org/web/20150504141315/http://jasonframe.co.uk/logfile/2009/01/php-5-3-exception-gotcha/)

Example (taken from the link above):

```
<?php
namespace test;

class Foo {
  public function test() {
    try {
      something_that_might_break();
    } catch (\Exception $e) { // <<<<<<<<<<< You must use the backslash
      // something
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: The link has died, please can you expand this answer with the correct code?

Comment: @servermanfail I added the link from archive.org and copied the example code

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the structure of Google's API is, and I'm not a real fluent PHP programmer, but you're catching a specific exception type of `Exception`, with which Google's `Google_Auth_Exception` may not inherit from.

Therefore, since your try-catch block is looking for an exception that is a member of `Exception` and the `Google_Auth_Exception` is perhaps not a member of `Exception`, then your try catch block will miss it.

Try catching the specific exception. This has happened to me before in many different languages.

### Edit

The link you posted inherits its exception from: [Google/Auth/Exception](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Auth/Exception.php)
Google/Auth/Exception inherits its exception from: [Google/Exception](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Exception.php)
Google/Exception extends `Exception`, which may, in this context be the `Exception` that your class is referring to.

It seems my justification for your try-catch block not catching an exception is completely wrong, but the wisdom could still be true. Try catching the specific exception, then use `instanceof` to see if PHP recognizes `Google_Auth_Exception` as a member of `Exception`.

Comment: Thanks, but all exception classes in PHP extends the built-in Exception, this is not the issue.

Comment: I figured that out and edited my answer. Did you try catching the specific instance of exception that is being thrown?

Comment: just so you know, the problem was that I was using a namespace and in this case PHP requires the use of the fully qualified class name, so it should be "\Exception".

Comment: I had absolutely no idea you were using a namespace, and I didn't care because I didn't think that it would make any kind of a difference. 

So, it WAS indeed trying to catch a different kind of exception? Just out of curiosity, if you were to perform an `instanceof` check on an unescaped `Exception` would that exception show membership of the namespace you were using? That kind of behavior is absolutely stupid! 

I'm going to add this to the list of reasons why I hate PHP. It silently let you go on and call an exception thinking everything was going to be Okay. How horrid.